# Where can I find data about traffic flow for European cities?

Tags: data-request, transportation, europe, traffic

I am doing a study to compare the consumption of fuel between US/Europe?

As I found some data in some cities in US, I still looking for data in Europe (mainly interested in data where I can show how many hours are wasted in traffic - in other words, how much fuel is wasted in traffic). Any city as as case study in Europe should be fine.

Comment: Please feel free to add your US Cities to our data collection https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection

Answer (score 4):

The UK [Department for Transport](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/department-for-transport) (DFT) provides a traffic data set for the city of London, for 2000 to 2013.

- [Main page](http://www.dft.gov.uk/traffic-counts/area.php)
- [London](http://www.dft.gov.uk/traffic-counts/area.php?region=London&la=City%20of%20London)
- [About](http://www.dft.gov.uk/traffic-counts/about.php)
- [Metadata PDF](http://data.dft.gov.uk/gb-traffic-matrix/all-traffic-data-metadata.pdf)

There are two main data sets:

1. **AADF - Annual average daily flow**

> AADF figures give the number of vehicles that will drive on that stretch of road on an average day of the year. For information on how AADFs are calculated, see the guidance on the Traffic Statistics pages on GOV.UK.
>
> AADF figures are presented as: Units = vehicles per day

2. **Traffic - Annual volume of traffic**

> Traffic figures give the total volume of traffic on the stretch of road for the whole year, and are calculated by multiplying the AADF by the corresponding length of road and by the number of days in the year (i.e. one vehicle travelling one mile each day for a year would equal 365 vehicle miles).
>
> Traffic figures are presented as: Units = thousand vehicle miles

Answer (score 2):

The National Institute of Statistics and Economic Studies in France has data on traffic for national highways, railways and air traffic. This is their open database on Quandl: https://www.quandl.com/data/INSEE

Just search for "traffic" within the database to see the datasets on traffic specifically. Also, when you look at each dataset, there's always a link to the left under "Validate." This shows you where the data was taken from so you can always look at the original source of the data. Hope this helps. [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Answer (score 1):

In this ['open traffic collection'](https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection) we collect several traffic flow/count sources (including the mentioned here)